# Finding probability of joint discrete rv

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and $Y$
>   geometric with parameter $p$. Find $P(Y>X)$. ($\bf independent$)

### Attempt

We know $p_X(x) = \frac{ e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x }{x!} $ and $p_Y(y) = (1-p)^{y-1} p$. Now, we have the region $\{(x,y) : y>x \}$ for integers $x,y$. We want to sum over this region. My thought is to first sum $y$ from $1$ to $\infty$ and $x$ is between $y$ and $\infty$. Thus,

$$ P(Y>X) = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} \sum_{x=y}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x }{x!} (1-p)^{y-1} p = pe^{-\lambda} \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{y-1} \sum_{x=y}^{\infty} \frac{ \lambda^x}{x!} = p e^{-\lambda} \frac{1}{1-1+p} \sum_{x=y}^{\infty} \frac{ \lambda^x}{x!} = e^{- \lambda} \sum_{x=y}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

Here is where I get stuck. My answer key says it should $e^{- \lambda p }$. But I cant get to this answer. Any help?

Comment: You did not mention that X and Y are independent. Everything you have done rests on this.

Comment: If you want to use a double summation it would work fine too. You are just summing over the wrong region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(Y>X)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(Y>n)P(X=n)\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^\infty (1-p)^n\left(\frac{ e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n }{n!}\right)\\
&=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(q\lambda)^n }{n!};\quad q=1-p\\
&=e^{-\lambda}e^{q\lambda}\\
&=e^{q\lambda-\lambda}=e^{-(1-q)\lambda}\\
&=e^{-\lambda p}
\end{align}

Comment: You forgot the lambda in the last step.

Comment: @StubbornAtom They canceled each other out, didn't they?

Comment: Umm ...   nope. Look again.

Comment: If not for the error in the last equation this answer gives the right solution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom oh my hahahaha so sorry I fixed it